# What is the best way to use and save or optimize these variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, save

I'm making a picker that chooses themes, and I would like to know if there is a better way than the one I'm using, thanks.

I'm currently saving like this `var saveSettings = "000";`, 0 is true 1 is false, for themes I'm saving with 0,1,2...4,5

**The code below is from function Start() {}**

```
function Start() {
    var savedSettings = app.LoadText(saveName, null, fileSettings);
    if(savedSettings.charAt(2) == 0 ) NumButtons="#969696", CountIcons="#616161", equalIcon="#ED9135";
    else if(savedSettings.charAt(2) == 1 ) NumButtons="#4285F4", CountIcons="#1f498c", equalIcon="#ED9135";
}
```

**The code below is from function picker() {}**

```
function Picker() {

if( themeName=="Material" )
{
    savedSettings = savedSettings.replaceAt(2, "1");
    app.SaveText("Theme", themeName, fileSettings);
    
    corIcon="#1f498c", corButton="#4285F4", corEqual="#ED9135", fonteButton="White", 
    fonteIcon="White", fonteSpecial="#ba472b", fonteEqual="White";
    
    //BTNs Theme
    btnShow0.SetStyle(corIcon, corIcon); //+
    btnShow0.SetTextColor(fonteIcon); //+
    btnShow1.SetStyle(corButton, corButton); //1
    btnShow1.SetTextColor(fonteButton); //1
    btnShow2.SetStyle(corButton, corButton); //2
    btnShow2.SetTextColor(fonteButton); //2
    btnShow3.SetStyle(corButton, corButton); //3
    btnShow3.SetTextColor(fonteButton); //3
    btnShow4.SetStyle(corEqual, corEqual);//=
    btnShow4.SetTextColor(fonteEqual); //=
}

else if(themeName == "...") {}
else if(themeName == "...") {}
else if(themeName == "...") {}
else if(themeName == "...") {}
}
```

**I should use array, but I don't know if it's the best strategy.**

```
var data = [{Name : "Material", color1="#....", color2="#....", colorFont1="#....", colorFont1="#...."},
            {Name : "Material2", color1="#....", color2="#....", colorFont1="#....", colorFont1="#...."}];

 ...

 function picker() {
    ...
    btnShow0.SetStyle(Material[color1]);
    btnShow0.SetStyle(Material[0.....4]);
 }
```

**Could some one help me?**

Comment: `var saveSettings = 000;` ... that's just `0`, since that's how numbers work - did you mean `"000"`

Comment: Yes, it's "000". It look like this "010", "113" or "014"

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at the "Factory Pattern", since it seems that  all you will be doing is changing one theme to another. Here is a link which describes the way to implement a factory pattern in JavaScript: https://www.dofactory.com/javascript/design-patterns/factory-method